# How to get Django custom form validator to work?

Tags: django, forms, validation

I'm working on a custom valdator for my Django forms. Inexplicably, I can't get the result I want. Here is my code

```
from django import forms
from django.core import validators
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from .models import Vote
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator


def use_one(value):
    if value != 1:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Value is not 1!")

class MyForm(forms.Form):


     main_form = forms.IntegerField(validators = [use_one], 
                                    label= 'Main', 
                                    required = False,
                                     widget = forms.NumberInput(
                                                   attrs={'id': 'mainInput',
                                                          'name': 'main,
                                                          'href': '#',
                                                          'value': '',
                                                          'class': "form-control"}))
```

Any thoughts?

**views.py**

```
form = MyForm()

main_result = request.GET.get(main_form)

form.fields['main_form_result'].initial = main_result

context = {form: form}
```

Comment: How do you use that form in the view?

Comment: Updated the above code with views logic

Comment: Well you never validate your form.

Comment: How come if I had a built-in validator, however, like `main_form = forms.IntegerField(validators = [MinValueValidator(0)])` I get a validation error raised, when I don't need to validate my form in the view?

Answer (score 0):

The Well you never validate your form. You should pass `request.GET` to the form, and let the form validate it, so:

```
def some_view(request):
    form = MyForm(request.GET)
    form.is_valid()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'some-template.html', context)
```

Often forms are submitted as POST request, especially if these create, update, or remove entities.

Comment: So previously, I was never validating my form, and the built in validator worked, like so: `main_form = forms.IntegerField(validators = [MinValueValidator(0)]) ` Could you briefly explain why I get a validation error raised here, when I don't validate my form in the view?

Comment: @nick_rinaldi: it will not raise a validator error if you do not pass it data. Are you sure it did not raise another error? A non-bounded form is not valid/invalid, that is simply unbounded. The `.is_valid()` will always return false, if you do not call it with `request.GET` or `request.POST` (or another dictionary-like object).

Comment: No, what I'm saying is the above code in my comment DOES raise a validator error, when I pass it data to the front end. Even if I call the .is_valid() on my form like in this code, `form = MyForm(request.GET)
    form.is_valid()` I receive an error saying that `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'none'`

Comment: @nick_rinaldi: `.is_valid()` is not supposed to raise exceptions: it catches all `ValidationError`s. So if that raises an error, that means something is broken. Can you share the traceback by editing the question?

Comment: I can't, I can't share my jobs codebase, so I altered the code in the question to create a sample problem.

Comment: @nick_rinaldi: well apparently in your form something has a `x.none`, (with `x` a variable) and since, `x` is `None`, that thus raises an error.

Comment: I can tell you that it traces back to django forms.py `self.full_clean()`, then `self._clean_fields()`, then `value = field.clean(value)`, then from models.py `return self.queryset.none()`

Comment: @nick_rinaldi: that likely means you have a `ModelChoiceField` where you have set `queryset=None`, but that should be a valid queryset, perhaps a `MyModel.objects.none()` (so an empty one), but not `None` itself.

Comment: Hmm.. okay. I am refactoring older code, so that may be why my implementations are having issues. Still what I am confused about is, previously, there is no `form.is_valid() `check in the view, at all. And the built in MinValueValidator will still raise an error if the input field is less than 0, i.e. -1. How come this is the case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239755/discussion-between-nick-rinaldi-and-willem-van-onsem).